# How to use ate and had eaten

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is correct 
Example. Mark ate all the chocolate when I got home . There was nothing left .

Mark had eaten all the chocolate when I got home . There was nothing left . Thanks

Comment: Why are you thanking Mark for eating all the chocolate?

Answer (score 2):

> Mark ate all the chocolate when I got home. There was nothing left.

This says that Mark waited for you to get home **before** he then proceeded to eat ALL of the chocolate.  The act of eating the chocolate happened AFTER or at the moment you got home.

I think the confusion is occurring because both the act of eating the chocolate and the time when you are describing the act are in the past but independent of each other.

While the verb '*ate*' is the past simple of *eat*, "Mark ate..." is past tense  - for example, "he ate the thing yesterday" - **you are also describing the event in the past, after it has happened**.

> Mark had eaten all the chocolate when I got home. There was nothing left.

You are still describing something that happened in the past but this is slightly different, it that it says: "Mark had already eaten ALL of the chocolate BEFORE you got home, but the result is the same...

"Mark had eaten..." is present perfect tense.

The present perfect tense refers to an action or state that occurred, either:

- At an indefinite time in the past (e.g., we have talked before), or
- Began in the past and continued to the present time (e.g., he has grown impatient over the last hour). The reference is the present day.

This tense is formed by have/has + the past participle.

"eaten" is a past participle--not a verb

Comment: I would  like  to know whether  Mark  had  eaten  is  a  present  perfect  or  past  perfect. I would  like  to know  why  the  use  of  present  perfect  was  dicussed  by  the user  who  answered  the  question

Comment: It is a past perfect. NeilB wrongly identifies it as present perfect, and then goes on to explain uses of the present perfect (not in the way I would do so). His explanation of the specific example is appropriate, though.